# create a total SharePoint application through Provider hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app

I have a question if we are able to create a total SharePoint application (e.g. Help desk.. raising help desk tickets) through Provider hosted app. Till now what we have done is created different provider hosted app and placed those app in Site pages but did not create a full application through provider hosted app. In fact I don’t know how to create a total application through provider hosted app? I have 2 questions here:

1. Is it possible to create a total SharePoint application (e.g. Help desk.. raising help desk tickets) based on Provider hosted app?
2. If it is possible then please tell me the steps or share link how we can create a total SP application through PHA.

I may be asking a easy question but waiting to get reply from you.

Comment: What does 'total application' mean? If you previously have created a provider hosted app, then you're already there. Maybe, for example, you want to add an App Part or other interactive elements to integrate your app with SharePoint more closely.

Comment: I know we can create app part but big question is how to create full application through PHA? Do any one knows how to create step by step?

Comment: Here's a nice simple one!
http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/building-apps-for-sharepoint-with-mvc/